# Can I attach a 2x4 even with joist top for screwing on new deck boards?

Tags: deck

I’m re doing a deck
I’ve replaced a number of old joists and am planning to leave in place the rest. They are 2x10 spanning 8 feet.

There were s lot of old nails that did not pull out cleanly. I am concerned they my new stainless screws will hit these old nails and cause me a bunch of trouble.  My plan is to sister a treated 2x4 even with the top of joist and screw the new deck boards to it.

Any problem with this idea?

Comment: The job of the joist is to hold weight from above.  Screwing down deck boards is to just keep them in place.  Using a 2x4 for screwing just hurts the pocket book.

Comment: @crip659 that’s what I’m thinking too.  It will add about 400 to this job.

Comment: The screws will find a way.

Comment: Assuming your old screws are all lined up, simply offset your new line of screws a suitable amount (an inch?) to ensure that you don't hit any old ones.

Comment: @Huesmann previous deck boards were nailed down by a trigger happy idiot 3 nails per joist.  I want my screws to have a consistent pattern of two per joust evenly spaced

Comment: When you predrill/countersink, you'll be able to feel if you're banging into a nail. Usually the drill bit and screw will just slip to the side a little. In the limited cases where that doesn't work well, predrill a little more.

Comment: If you ground off w/e was left then it's fine. If you peened them over, not so much, but also, still kinda fine. You camming-off the screw head and damaging the flooring when it decides to go sideways, and/or snapping SS screws, is the main concern. - You could flip the joists over. W/e.... it's fine. Also, they used x3? Your x2 will go in between those (as long as you're ok with a rather severe minimum edge distance of them both being nearly in the center).... Hopefully.

Comment: Also, with those 2x4s, you're like 3" away from the end of the boards with where it's screwed down. It doesn't violate code, just my OCD. - Screws not where they should be is worse than a few surface disappearances. - If you're not doing the screws with the cover plugs then w/e. If you are, and you didn't gut the whole thing, then that's on you if it's not 110% perfect.

Comment: @Mazura yeah I don’t see a problem with the screw holding the deck board  in place all the weight will be  born by the joist. On the few but joints I’ll have the butt will occur over the joist not the 2x4

Comment: The butt will occur over the joist, but the screws will be 6" away from each other instead  of 3". That's what I do at parties; try to figure out why this guy's house looks wack. **Use Tiger Claws** and it'd be fine.

Comment: No at butts I’ll screw into joist.  And only one side of joist gets a 2x4  80% of the deck has 15’8” runs  I’m using 16’ 2x6 kdat prodigy deck boards from Culpepper

Comment: @Mazura actually you  have a point about the screw layout getting  wacky at butts. Would it be awful if I butted on top of the 2x4 ? https://www.culpeperwood.com/products2/decking/culpeper-prodigy-the-ultimate-deck-board/

Comment: Yes, that violates [code](https://www.chicago.gov/dam/city/depts/bldgs/general/EZPERMIT/PorchGuidelinesMay2011.pdf). Note, I have some more than 10yo composite decking that has shrunk and the butt joint is separated by almost a 1/2". However, they both land on their own joist, a sistered, double joist hung, 2x10 running down the center. - It's questionable to butt joint on a single joist in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148429/discussion-between-kris-and-mazura).

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate but if you hit a nail when predrilling, then you're stuck with an empty hole—less than attractive.